# Echoing dynamic variables

Tags: php, variables

I have $Page1Title declared in a config file and I have $PageID declared on each individual page. How would I go about echoing the $Page1Title variable using the $PageID variable? Almost like this `$PageTitle = $Page{$PageID}Title;` type of thing?!

UPDATE:

Sorted it with

```
$PageTitle = 'Page'.$PageID.'Title';
<?=$$PageTitle?>
```

Comment: Instead of [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), you might want to consider an array for that - in particular since the `1` indicates a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use var of var

```
$var = 'Page' . $i . 'Title';
echo $$var;
```

Comment: That's what I have done, see edit! Cheers.